# Use console.log within form action=".php"

Tags: php

I want to debug the `upload.php` referenced by `<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone">`

My problem is that neither `console.log` nor echo'd `alert`s are working when I call the `upload.php` by `form action`.

Logging does work when I open the `upload.php` directly but PHP seems to handle it differently when called in the way I described in the first line of the text.

Now I don't know what terms I should google for, "form action echo" only gives me results of people who want to output a form and "form action alert" is full of results how to confirm a user's "send message" click.

Comment: I don't understand any of what you need. Can you examplify better?

Comment: I don't see why you're trying to use JavaScript to debug PHP. Surely just a `var_dump()` would show you what's going on?

Comment: No, var_dump() also doesn't raise any output in the console. I will now use the networking tab of Chrome's console like described in the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either xdebug to debug your PHP code or look in the network tab of your browser what is returned as result of action is performed per ajax and you have vardump in your code.

Comment: Thanks, the network tab isn't the most comfy solution but it works the way it should :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're intent on using JavaScript to debug your PHP code:

- If you're using jQuery, you could do:

  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(whatever);
  }
- With plain JavaScript: `<form onSubmit="myFunction();">`

Then in your myFunction(), you call your `console.log()`.

But, as others have pointed out, I'm not sure you really should be debugging PHP code with JavaScript.